# Uncaught ReferenceError: cnt is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

I want to click button and count number but it's not work.
and error message: Uncaught ReferenceError: cnt is not defined
This is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Make777</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <button type="button" class="btn-click" onclick="dongjak_button();">CLICK</button>
  <span>You Clicked This Button <span id="number"></span>Times!!!!!!</span>

  <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
"use strict";

function dongjak_button(){
    cnt = 0;
    cnt++;
    document.getElementById("number").value = cnt;
}
```

Help. I hope `cnt` variable works. and show on html

Comment: Are you sure you want to reset `cnt` to zero every time you click the button…?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in strict mode, and you didn't declare your `cnt` variable. See [MDN's docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).

You also can't change `value` on a `span` — you'll need `textContent` instead. And, your `cnt` will reset every time, so you'll want to store the variable outside of your function. All in all:

```js
// stored outside the function so it increments rather than resets
let cnt = 0;
function dongjak_button(){
    cnt++;
    // use textContent, not value; also add a space
    document.getElementById("number").textContent = cnt + ' ';
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn-click" onclick="dongjak_button();">CLICK</button>
<span>You Clicked This Button <span id="number"></span>Times!!!!!!</span>
```

Comment: Thanks, But it cannot show on html. I want to show webpage 'cnt' variable

Comment: Sorry, I missed the other error (using `value` instead of `textContent`). I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `var` or `let` to declare JavaScript variables.

Read more here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp

```js
"use strict";

function dongjak_button(){
    let cnt = 0;
    cnt++;
    document.getElementById("number").textContent = cnt;
}
```

Code still won't work though, because you need to get the count from `#number` first.

```html
"use strict";

function dongjak_button(){
    const number = document.getElementById("number");
    const value = number.textContent;
    
    let cnt = value ? Number(value) : 0;
    cnt++;
    number.textContent = cnt;
}
```

Comment: A `span` doesn’t have a `.value`…

Comment: Great point! This terrible question through me off.